# Why does Docker "give executable file `/bin/sh` not found in $PATH"?

Tags: linux, docker

Can some figure out why this Dockerfile

```
FROM docker.io/fluent/fluent-bit:1.6-debug
RUN ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Copenhagen /etc/localtime
```

gives

```
STEP 1: FROM docker.io/fluent/fluent-bit:1.6-debug
STEP 2: RUN /usr/local/bin/ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Copenhagen /etc/localtime
2021-02-20T19:44:50.000358546Z: executable file `/bin/sh` not found in $PATH: No such file or directory
error running container: error creating container for [/bin/sh -c /usr/local/bin/ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Copenhagen /etc/localtime]: : exit status 1
Error: error building at STEP "RUN /usr/local/bin/ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Copenhagen /etc/localtime": error while running runtime: exit status 1
```

If I do

```
$ docker run -ti fluent-bit:1.6-debug sh
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Copenhagen /etc/localtime
```

then it works...

Answer (score 4):

Because your docker.io/fluent/fluent-bit:1.6-debug base image is based on a distroless base image: https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/installation/docker#multi-architecture-images

You can enter the shell and execute command in the container because you are using a debug image version that has busybox in it
https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless#debug-images

More about distroless:
https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/blob/master/README.md

To achieve what you want do this, specify that the shell is the busybox sh function instead of the default /bin/sh that is nonexistent here.

```
FROM docker.io/fluent/fluent-bit:1.6-debug
SHELL ["busybox", "sh", "-c"]
RUN ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Copenhagen /etc/localtime
```

Keep in mind that you can do this only with a debug image version. Also keep in mind that distroless images are meant only to run your program and nothing else.

**UPDATE:**

This format will also work:

```
    FROM docker.io/fluent/fluent-bit:1.6-debug
    RUN ["ln", "-sf",  "/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Copenhagen", "/etc/localtime"]
```

Because https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run

*RUN has 2 forms:*

- *RUN  (shell form, the command is run in a shell, which by
  default is /bin/sh -c on Linux or cmd /S /C on Windows)*
- *RUN ["executable", "param1", "param2"] (exec form)*

*The exec form makes it possible to avoid shell string munging, and to RUN commands using a base image that does not contain the specified shell executable.*

Comment: I get the same error. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, see log: https://gist.github.com/zsolt2177/5858aa091c9d0e67d1d1da62c5810112

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM docker.io/fluent/fluent-bit:1.6-debug
RUN ["ln", "-sf",  "/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Copenhagen", "/etc/localtime"]
```